# Vuetify switch sync with model

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have data table with vuetify v-switch inside it. When user click on v-switch it toggle itself. I want to restore it to previous state when user cancels the swal(sweet alert). The switch should revert back to active if it is inactive and vice-versa.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="users" item-key="pk" :loading="loading" hide-default-footer :items-per-page="i_per_page">
  <template v-slot:item.switch="{ item }">
    <v-tooltip bottom v-if="item.is_active=='active'">
       <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <div v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
             <v-switch :id="String(item.user_id)" :loading='switchLoader'   true-value="active" false-value="null" v-model="item.is_active" @click="toggle_status(item.user_id, item.is_active, $event)"></v-switch>
          </div>
       </template>
     <small v-if="item.is_active">Suspend</small>
   </v-tooltip>
   <v-tooltip bottom v-if="item.is_active=='null'">
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
       <div v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
         <v-switch :loading='switchLoader' true-value="active" false-value="null" v-model="item.is_active" @click="toggle_status(item.user_id, item.is_active, $event)"></v-switch>
       </div>
     </template>
     <small>Activate</small>
   </v-tooltip>

 </template>

</v-data-table>

<script>
  methods: {
    toggle_status(user_id, value, e) {
      console.log(e)
      if (value == 'null') {
        this.action = '0'
        swal.fire({
          title: 'Are you sure you want to deactivate user?',
          showDenyButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: `Deactivate`,
          denyButtonText: `Cancel`
        }).then(result => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            this.toggle_user(user_id, value)
          } else {
            return false
          }
        })
      } else if (value == 'active') {
        this.action = '1'
        swal.fire({
          title: 'Are you sure you want to activate user?',
          showDenyButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: `Activate`,
          denyButtonText: `Cancel`
        }).then(result => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            this.toggle_user(user_id, value)
          } else {
            return false
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is basically an abbreviated tag for `value` and `@input`.
You need to handle input change for v-switch on your own so you shouldn't use v-model.
Now the bindings of v-model are different for different components. For e.g. Vuetify v-switch component binds `v-model` to `input-value` as we can see from the API: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-switch/#props-input-value

So basically, writing `v-model="item.is_active"` is internally same as `:input-value="item.is_active" @change="item.is_active = $event.target.value"`

So you can rewrite your code as `:input-value="item.is_active @change="toggle_status(item.user_id, item.is_active, $event)"`
(Note you shouldn't use @click event here as it may get triggered before input-value is updated)

You can reset the v-switch if user cancels swal:

```js
const i = this.users.findIndex((user) => user.user_id == user_id);
this.users[i].is_active = e;
swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure you want to deactivate user?',
  showDenyButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: `Deactivate`,
  denyButtonText: `Cancel`
}).then(result => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    this.toggle_user(user_id, value)
  } else {
    const i = this.users.findIndex((user) => user.user_id == user_id);
    this.users[i].is_active = e == "active" ? "null" : "active"; // reset is_active if user cancels the swal
  }
})
```

Comment: I have successfully changed the value of is_active using loop in the array. But switch is not updated in the v-data-table.

Comment: @AjayKhrolia Perhaps it's an issue with reactivity. Check: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: I had changed input-value to v-model and now it syncs with the value from data=>item

Comment: But I suppose now your @change won't get triggered if you're using v-model. data=>item value syncing should happen using input-value too.

Comment: @AjayKhrolia I've edited the above code a little with how to make the change while maintaining reactivity. Here's a codesandbox to see it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-bartik-7rffz?file=/index.html:3277-3462

Comment: @change still works with v-model, your code works the same as with v-model. it is a solution to this too!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following steps?

1. Remove the v-switch binding (`v-model`) to `item.is_active`
2. On the `toggle_status` method, get the current value through the event, and change to look like this:

   ```
   toggle_status: (event) {
     const value = event.target.value
     console.log('value: ', value)
     if (value === 'active') {
       ... // Insert the same code for the swall calls in here
     }
   }
   ```

And surely, in the `<template>` you should be doing like this
`<v-switch ... @click="toggle_status($event)"></v-switch>`